# Can Silverlight 4 and 5 plugins live side by side?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-plugin

With SL plugin 5.0.60818.0 I get an error when I open this page:
http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Docking/FirstLook

(I hope someone from telerik sees this).

I uninstalled SL 5 and reinstalled SL 4, and the page opens fine.

Is there some way I can have both SL 4 and SL 5 runtimes installed, and just configure my browser to use the one I want?

The SL4 and SL5 SDK's can live side-by-side, why not the plugins?

Comment: It seems to be a know issue with teleriks controls at the moment. We have a customer solution we have to release during the spring where we need them to have it fixed, else we'll have to discard their controls completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not on the same OS.  You can create a Virtual Machine using Microsoft Virtual PC and use that for one of the plug-ins.